# AngularJS pre-fill input fields based on data from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pre-fill a form with a data from a controller.

Simple code looks like

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input name="widget.title" ng-model="widget.title">
    <input name="widget.content" ng-model="widget.content">
    <button ng-click="set('foo')">set to foo</button>
</div>
```

and

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.widget = {title: 'abc'};
        $scope.widget = {content: 'test'};
        $scope.set = function(new_title) {
            this.widget.title = new_title;
        }
    });
```

but it always pre-fill only last input field

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b40nLuf2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you overrides the first `$scope.widget ($scope.widget = {title:'abc'})` with the second `($scope.widget = {content:'test'})`.

You have to define one object `$scope.widget` with two attributes, title and content, in this way:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.widget = {
            title: 'abc',
          content: 'test'
        };
        $scope.set = function(new_title) {
            this.widget.title = new_title;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code snippets

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.widget = {title: 'abc',content: 'test'};
        $scope.set = function(new_title) {
            this.widget.title = new_title;
        }
    });
```

JSFIDDLE : [click here to see](http://jsfiddle.net/b40nLuf2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your object like this

```
$scope.widget = {
         title: 'abc',
          content: 'test'
};
```